# Cocos2d: Activity class & CCLayer class

Tags: android, eclipse, cocos2d-android, cclayer, ccscene

Im building a game using eclipse and now I wanted to use **Cocos2d** **engine**. My problem is I want to merge my done program and sliding menu of cocos2d engine. And now my question is how can I extend my **Menu Class** to **Activity class** so I can call onCreate and setContentView for my XML and to extend also to **CCLayer Class** to make my Menu Class connected on my Sliding Menu of Cocos2d.

thanks for any suggestions and help. And please apologize my question.

**UPDATE:** heres the code

```
public class Menu extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        .... //some codes here
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // some codes here.
    }
}
```

and here's the method that I wanted to use from **CCLayer** but it needs to extend it from that class.

```
public static CCScene scene()
{
    CCScene scene = CCScene.node();
    CCLayer layer = new Menu();
    scene.addChild(layer);
    return scene;
}
```

Comment: You can only extend a single class in Java; that's just how the language is.

Comment: android is java. cannot extend two classes.

Comment: If you provide some code someone might be able to offer some alternatives.

Comment: sir @GeorgeBaker please check out the update. I already post my codes. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Can't extend 2 classes in Java. But you could use interfaces, or the observer / listener pattern.

Comment: So is there a way so I can use their method from both classes?

Comment: If you extend `Activity`, you can use all its functions, and since your other class has static function, simply use `CCScene.scene()`. Or am i missing something?

Comment: i have an error on the **new Menu()** it says that `type mismatch cannot convert Menu to CCLayer`

Comment: You can't assign an object `Menu` to a `CCLayer`, they aren't related.
If you want to use `Menu` as a `CCLayer`, you should do something like:
1) create `public interface CCLayer`, and declare all the APIs (functions) that you need.
2) create `public class Menu extends Activity implements CCLayer`, and implement all the functions that were in the original `CCLayer` class.
3) now you can type `CCLayer menu = new Menu()`

Comment: How do I declare API functions? what are those? is it like copying the whole CCLayer java class in CClayer interface class?

Comment: interface is similar to header (.h) in c++

Comment: im not familiar in c++ language though.

Comment: 1) `public interface myInterface { public void myFunction(); }`
2) `public class myClass implements myInterface { @Override public void myFunction() { System.out.println("myFunction"); } }`